# System File Watcher C# locking Directory?

Tags: c#

I have a system file watcher monitoring the Downloads directory of the user in C#.The program is a windows service and each time it finds a file that has been dropped into or downloaded into the downloads directory the files are moved to another directory. As the service is running, when a download attempts, it will fail. Chrome just says `Failed - Download error`, without description of what the error is. I can only assume my windows service is locking the directory by watching it, so nothing can be downloaded to it. When the windows service is turned off, I can download normally again. I'm pretty new to C#, so I am unfamiliar with common errors, but here's my code:

```
    private void watch()
    {
        string pathUser = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
        path = Path.Combine(pathUser, "Downloads");
        watcher.Path = path;
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                     | NotifyFilters.FileName;
        watcher.Filter = "*.*";
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        String pUser = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);

        String directoryName = Destination;
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directoryName);
        if (dirInfo.Exists == false)
            Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);

        List<String> MyFiles = Directory
                           .GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

        foreach (string file in MyFiles)
        {
            FileInfo mFile = new FileInfo(file);
            // to remove name collusion
            if (new FileInfo(dirInfo + "\\" + mFile.Name).Exists == false)
            {
                bool flag = true;
                while (flag)
                {
                    if (!IsFileLocked(file, 1))
                    {
                        mFile.MoveTo(dirInfo + "\\" + mFile.Name);
                        flag = false;
                    }
                }


            }    
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**
I tried filtering out the temporary download extensions before moving but I still seem to get the error. Here is my attempt:

```
    String[] ignoreExt = { "crdownload","download", "temp", "tmp"};

    private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        String pUser = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);

        String directoryName = Destination;
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directoryName);
        if (dirInfo.Exists == false)
            Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);

        List<String> MyFiles = Directory
                           .GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

        foreach (string file in MyFiles)
        {
            FileInfo mFile = new FileInfo(file);
            // to remove name collusion
            if (new FileInfo(dirInfo + "\\" + mFile.Name).Exists == false)
            {
                bool flag = true;
                while (flag)
                {
                    if (!IsFileLocked(file, 1))
                    {
                        if (mFile.Extension != ignoreExt[0] || mFile.Extension != ignoreExt[1] || mFile.Extension != ignoreExt[2] || mFile.Extension != ignoreExt[3])
                        {
                            mFile.MoveTo(dirInfo + "\\" + mFile.Name);
                           // Clipboard.SetText(dirInfo + "\\" + mFile.Name);
                            flag = false;
                        }
                    }
                }                    
            }    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible that you start your copy too early when the download has not yet finished to write the file.

Comment: How is `IsFileLocked` implemented?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you download something with Chrome it creates an `Unconfirmed` file like this: `Unconfirmed 50329.crdownload`

I tested it manually on my system by dragging this file away, result -> `Failed to Download - Error`

I think that your Service is moving this file, before Chrome can finish the download.

**EDIT:**

For the example with Chrome download files you could check the file extension like this:

```
if(mFile.Extension != "crdownload")
{
    ...
}
```

[MSDN FileSystemInfo.Extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.extension(v=vs.110).aspx)

**EDIT2:**
Use instead of the Array a List:

```
List<String> ignoreExt = new  List<String>() { "crdownload","download", "temp", "tmp"};
```

Then you can check your extension like this:

```
if (ignoreExt.Where(x => x == mFile.Extension).ToList().Count == 0)
{
    mFile.MoveTo(dirInfo + "\\" + mFile.Name);
   // Clipboard.SetText(dirInfo + "\\" + mFile.Name);
    flag = false;
}
```

Make sure that you are `using System.Linq;`

On this way you can add some new extensions without an if about countless rows ;)

Comment: Well, that's not a "coding" answer at all but you are so right :) +1 *Edit: Just curious though, doesn't Chrome lock the file while the download is going on?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers, I'll give it a shot! @uteist  I thought chrome would automatically lock the file too, which is why I check if the file is locked before attempting to move it, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @uteist No, Chrome doesn't. The move was possible without UAC request or warning, that the file is in use or something else. An coding answer would be a check if the file extension is ".crdownload". But this would only cover Chrome download files. I don't know what else could be possible. Give me some seconds to edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help @NikBo. I implemented your suggestions and unfortunately the download still fails. I included an update for my newly added code.

Comment: @btald1331 Don't use `||` on this way it's every time true. When you use `&&` it should work.

Comment: To clarify your problem. Currently you check `"crdownload" != "crdownload" or "crdownload" != "download" ...` you see, the file extension couldn't be `crdownload`and `download` at the same time ;)

Comment: @NikBo that was the problem. I feel especially stupid for making such a beginners mistake with experience in UNIX friendly languages. Thank you!

Comment: @btald1331 Please check my second edit. This could make the checking easier ;)